# Deleting a CKRecord is really confusing

Tags: ios, xcode, cloudkit, ckrecord

So I'm having a really weird problem, I suppose I either dont understand how CloudKit works under the hood or I encountered a bug in CloudKit.

So, the issue looks like this:

**App initial state:**

I have 5 "Package" records, lets call them A, B, C, D, E.

**User action**

The user will delete "Package" record E and at some later point in time he will press a refresh button which will fetch all current "Package" records from the cloud.

**The problem**

When the user presses the refresh button, the app will basically look at the existing locally stored "Package" records, and will create a CKQuery with a predicate that should fetch any other records that do not exist locally. The next step is basically calling the **[database performQuery: inZoneWithID:completionHandler:]** method.

The surprise shows up when I get the results, which contain the "Package" record E that the user previously deleted.

This doesnt seem to be right to me...

**The steps I took to debug:**

1. Right after deleting the "Package" record E, I created a CKFetchRecordsOperation and tried to fetch the deleted record. The result was as expected: I got a "Record not found". I'm cool here.
2. Thinking there might be some delays on the server side, I put a dispatch_after block and launched the same fetch operation I did in point 1 but just after 30 seconds. The result was still as expected: I got the "Record not found" error.
3. Performed the same test as I did in point 2 but with a delay of 100 seconds and ... surprise, the CKFetchRecordsOperation operation returned the deleted record E package. The weird thing is that somethings it will still return an error, but sometimes will just plainly return the deleted object.

And now the really weird part: This does not happen with record A, B, C and D, the single difference between all theses records are their names. This does not make any sense.

I filled a bug report and the reply I got was this:

***This is correct behavior. Queries are eventually consistent so the deletes may not immediately be reflected when querying. Fetching the deleted record by ID via a CKFetchRecordsOperation should return a CKErrorUnknownItem right away.***

While this is partially true, this does not seems to be the case with what I'm seeing.

**Code**

1. Deleting the record E with name DS2000330803AS, the check CKFetchRecordsOperation operation returns an error with Record not found. All good here.

> ```
> CKContainer *container = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
> CKDatabase *privateDB = [container privateCloudDatabase]; 
>
> CKRecordID *recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName: @"DS2000330803AS"];
>
> CKModifyRecordsOperation *operation = [[CKModifyRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordsToSave: nil recordIDsToDelete: @[recordID]];
> operation.database = privateDB;
>
> [operation setModifyRecordsCompletionBlock:^(NSArray<CKRecord *> * _Nullable savedRecords,
>                                          NSArray<CKRecordID *> * _Nullable deletedRecordIDs,
>                                          NSError * _Nullable error) {
>
>     CKFetchRecordsOperation *fetchOperation = [[CKFetchRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordIDs:@[recordID]];
>     fetchOperation.database = privateDB;
>     [fetchOperation setPerRecordCompletionBlock:^(CKRecord * _Nullable record, CKRecordID * _Nullable recordID, NSError * _Nullable error){
>         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
>     }];
> }];
> ```

2. Placing a NSTimer in my VC just to test the Record deletion, this piece of code will return the deleted record:

> ```
> [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:100 repeats:NO block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
>
>     CKContainer *container = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
>     CKDatabase *privateDB = [container privateCloudDatabase];
>
>     CKRecordID *recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@"DS2000330803AS"];
>
>     CKFetchRecordsOperation *fetchOperation = [[CKFetchRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordIDs: @[recordID]];
>     fetchOperation.database = privateDB;
>     [fetchOperation setPerRecordCompletionBlock:^(CKRecord * _Nullable record, CKRecordID * _Nullable recordID, NSError * _Nullable error){
>         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
>     }];
>
>     [privateDB addOperation: fetchOperation];
> }];
> ```

3. The piece of code that fetches all the existing records by pressing a refresh button which the user can press at any time. I simplified this code a bit to just expose the problem, basically the performQuery returns the DS2000330803AS record, and for the sake of testing my sanity, I'm adding a CKFetchRecordsOperation to fetch the record again, which of course does return it without any issues.

> ```
> CKContainer *container = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
> CKDatabase *privateDB = [container privateCloudDatabase];
>
> NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue: YES];
> CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Package" predicate:predicate];
>
> [privateDB performQuery:query
>      inZoneWithID:nil       completionHandler:^(NSArray<CKRecord *> * _Nullable results, NSError * _Nullable error) {
>
>     [results enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CKRecord * _Nonnull record, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
>
>         NSLog(@"Record ID: %@", record.recordID);
>
>         CKFetchRecordsOperation *fetchOperation = [[CKFetchRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordIDs: @[record.recordID]];
>         fetchOperation.database = privateDB;
>         [fetchOperation setPerRecordCompletionBlock:^(CKRecord * _Nullable record, CKRecordID * _Nullable recordID, NSError * _Nullable error){
>             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
>         }];
>
>         [privateDB addOperation: fetchOperation];
>     }];   
> }];
> ```

Other notes: I removed and commented pretty much everything related to CloudKit and the above code is the only one that interacts with CloudKit. I'm testing with a single device at the moment.

I know the CKQuery can have a better NSPredicate, but now I try to understand why I have this issue.

P.s. When I added the first implementation of CloudKit to my app, I tried to keep it as simple as possible, without any fancy syncing stuff. It worked just fine for a year, then I started getting reports from my users that they cannot delete some records in production.

Any hints guys on how I should further debug this?

Thank you!

Comment: [Edit] your question with relevant code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: the time it takes a record to update is not known. there is some indexing that can be time consuming. Here is an answer I gave but the difference is adding records although pay attention to the language about deletes. How i would handle those is keep a cache of deleted records. if they are not in the results i would flush the cache. Basically think of locally stitching the results to make them the same as the user expects. Link-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729601/how-to-update-data-in-tableview-without-the-delay-using-cloudkit-when-creating-n/42731220#42731220

Comment: iCloud isn't Oracle. Imagine things on their side; there must a farm of iCloud servers, all busy syncing with each other, its quite reasonable to expect some latency. I up voted https://stackoverflow.com/users/3641744/agibson007 answer cause its a good solution. If you find that CKFetchRecordsOperation returns the correct result too maybe that way the go alternatively if you don't want to try caching locally.

Comment: Thank you guys for your input. I totally agree with agibson007 answer with dealing with these delays, but I still feel there is something more to this issue. I mean, I understand that the indexing stuff can take a lot of time but, if you delete a record and then you open the app after 24 or 48 hours and you fetch the entire list of records and you still get back the deleted record then this does not seem to be right. Imagine you install the app on a new device and when everything gets fetched from the cloud the new device will also get the deleted record.

Comment: Andy I hear you and could not really understand if that was happening from your question. Can you give any more details of the specific record?

Comment: @agibson007 Sorry for not making this more clear! Honestly I dont exactly understand, the record is pretty simple and it has two queryable indexes and pretty much nothing else. What is weird is that I see inconsistent results, like sometimes the app will be able to delete a record and it will be gone for good and sometimes the record will just refuse to get deleted.  I'm trying to find out more information about this, but I'm quite afraid that it might just start working on its own and I hate those kinds of situations :)

Comment: andy- are you sure that the record id you are using is the record id of the record you want to delete?  looking back at the code from a mobile device it looks like you are creating a record id rather than using the existing id. In code section 1.

Comment: agibson007 yes, I'm just using the unique string "DS2000330803AS" as the record name for the record I want to delete, these strings are basically some unique IDs that I just use as the record name to make it more easier for future debugging.

Comment: It seems to me although I may be wrong that you are confusing RecordType and RecordName.  An example record name would be 
C5F2D5F1-1D73-40CE-B862-9DDFD4B368AB.  It is assigned by CloudKit not by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up record Type and record Name(String of CKRecordID). Name is assigned by CloudKit(Typically) and type is set by you.  I would bet it was auto assigned but I would have to see how the record was saved. It would be telling to see a screenshot of your CloudKit Dashboard.

In your block of code in 
1) you are trying to delete the record name of some record using the record type.  That is why you get the error "Record not found"
2) Same as you are still using Record Type and not record name
3) Fetches the record because it is actually using the assigned record.recordID.

This is my gut on the situation.  As far as deleting and refreshing please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3641744/agibson007) on stitching records to keep UI and database in sync.

Comment: I double checked the code and still not sure if I confuse the record name and type, I actually think I dont. According to apple's documentation, one can create a CKRecordID by providing its a meaningful string "you are free to use names that have more meaning to your app or to the user, as long as each name is unique within the specified zone."  This is exactly what I'm doing, I'm using the DS2000330803AS string as an ID because I know these strings will always be unique.

Comment: Do you care to screenshot Record E from the Dashboard just to see it?  I don't doubt you but I was going off my best guess and available info.  If it was created in Dashboard it is likely a unique string assigned by CloudKit.

Comment: Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xm3kv636w8m69l/Screenshot%202017-07-14%2017.25.57.png?dl=0   The weird thing is that I managed to delete this record from the dashboard, and now it seems that it got out of that "stuck" state and it can be also deleted from the app (If I recreate it), I guess this is now irrelevant because its an entirely new record. These are the things that scare me a lot when implementing a framework... we all recall the Core Data in the cloud fiasco...