# CloudKit: Internal Error with CKModifyRecordsOperation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cloudkit

I'm having a problem with CloudKit that I can't figure out. I hoping someone has some ideas or insight. I'm randomly getting an `Internal Error` from a `CKModifyRecordsOperation` with the description: `Couldn't decrypt record returned from the server in response to our save of record`.

**Details**

My app has several local objects that get synced to CloudKit. Each object type has a separate CloudKit RecordType, and each local type has its own updater, which creates its own `CKModifyRecordsOperation` for that object type.

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
let op = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: records, recordIDsToDelete: nil)
op.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { (modifiedRecords: [CKRecord]?, _: [CKRecordID]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
   let remoteError = RemoteError(cloudKitError: error as NSError?)
   let remoteRecords = modifiedRecords?.compactMap { RemoteRecord(record: $0)} ?? []
   completion(remoteRecords, remoteError)
}
database.add(op)
```

The `RemoteError` and `RemoteRecord` types are just helpers that create a more app-friendly version of the Error and Records from CloudKit.

**What I've Observed**

I don't think this is related to malformed `CKRecord` objects, since I can save the same record over and over again with no problem. Then, randomly, this occurs.

This does seem to happen when I've got two `Updater` objects sending `CKModifyRecordsOperations` very close to each other. While this occurs very often with no issues, the only time I see the problem is when this is the case (so far).

When the issue occurs, I first get a `Zone Busy` error for the second submitted operation, followed by the `Internal Error` as above, which is related to the first submitted operation.

Perhaps the first operation encounters some sort of issue, which causes the second to receive the `Zone Busy`. I'm not sure.

**Ideas**

While I have no idea what might be the cause, in thinking about it, I wonder if having two operations submitted very close together is somehow causing CloudKit problems? Seems hard to believe, but I don't see another reason.

I may try to rework my code to batch my modifications, but it seems odd that CloudKit couldn't handle this. And, again, it *does* handle it quite often.

**Thoughts?**

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be causing this, or other things to try to debug it? I suppose it could just be a CloudKit problem that I'll have to deal with. But ideally it's just something simple I'm doing that I can fix.

I have filed a bug report with Apple, as they request in the documentation for `Internal Error`.

Thank you.

Comment: I quickly are the saved fired off? And how soon until the next save is fired.

Comment: The two operations are sent almost at the same time. In essence, the first is created and sent, and then the second. So, they are within a few function calls of each other.

Comment: Are the two operations on the same record by chance?

Comment: They are two different records, though the second record does have a `CKReference` to the first, as well as has its `parent` property set to the first. The first record already exists in iCloud and is being updated, whereas the second record is new.

Comment: My guess is even though the reference is not changed in a meaningful way the first record is causing a Save error for the second as the indexing is not complete. You may need to redownload the first record before creating the reference for the second. Possibly fire it off in the completion block. Hope this makes sense but I bet it is the issues as CloudKit is not instantaneous and it is doing some indexing or tombstoning or something and the ref is old after the first save and while the second is trying to be saved

Comment: @agibson007, your last question sparked another idea: maybe because of the reference, there is a moment in time on iCloud where if the parent is in the middle of an update while a new child is added, it gets into a bad state. If it’s some kind of timing issue on the server, that might explain why it works much of the time. I will try to batch these and see if the issue remains. Unfortunately that will require some reworking of my app, but I am running out of ideas and need to find a way around this. Thank you for your discussion..

Comment: I just know that sometimes the indexing a new records takes time. Sometimes way more than you think. Similar but different you can see the delay in new record or changes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729601/how-to-update-data-in-tableview-without-the-delay-using-cloudkit-when-creating-n/42731220#42731220  Would explain the save with outdated reference

Comment: Thank you, @agibson007. I will try both of these approaches and post back what I find. Apple did reach out and ask for logs, so maybe we will get some insight from them as well.

Comment: Let me know what you find out

Comment: I implemented a batching scheme in my app, so now send these updates as a single `CKModifyRecordsOperation`. So far this evening, I have not been able to repro the issue. Of course, it was random, so I'll keep trying. I'll post again if I hear back from Apple.