# CloudKit does not retrieve record that should be there and retrievable

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, completionhandler, ckrecord

I have a function that creates a new record in CloudKit. Once that record was successfully created it calls a function called refresh() which will call some other function that queries for the record I just created. However, it says I created the record, but it never goes inside of the next query which is telling me that the new record may not be reaching CloudKit in time before it is being queried for. Incidentally, if I were to look in the database, the record WAS created correctly.

Creating new record function:

```
func saveCreatedGroup2(){
    let Group = CKRecord(recordType: "Group")
    print(groupName)
    Group.setObject(groupName as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "groupName")
    Group.setObject(groupDesc as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "groupDesc")
    Group.setObject(publicOrPrivate as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "PublicOrPrivate")
    Group.setObject(members as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "memberUsernames")
    Group.setObject(leaders as CKRecordValue?, forKey: "leaders")

    database.save(Group) { (savedRecord, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }else{
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
            print("SAVED RECORD, CREATED NEW GROUP!!!!")
            // IT DOES SAY THIS^
            thisTeamName = selectedCellName
            createdNewGroup = false
            self.refresh()
            }
        }

    }

}
```

refresh() function:

```
func refresh(){
    tempThisGroupTuple = []
    sortedTupleArray = []
    otherTeam = []
    otherSortedArray = []
    tempOtherTeamTuple = []
    canSwitchViews = false
    if (canRefresh == false){
    print ("ABANDONED")
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    }else{
    loadGroupPage()
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.requestsTableView.reloadData()
    self.groupFeedTableView.reloadData()
    }
    }
}
```

loadGroupPage() (querying for just created record) function - prints line that is before query, but does not print line that is inside query!:

```
func loadGroupPage() {
    print("loadingf group pagew...\(thisTeamName)") // PRINTS THIS

    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "groupName = %@", thisTeamName)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Group", predicate: pred)
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    operation.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
    var canJoin = false
    var requestVisible = false
    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord!) in

        if record != nil{

            self.OurGroup = record

            groupMembs = (record.object(forKey: "memberUsernames") as! Array) // loads group members
            print("original groupMembs: \(groupMembs)") // DOES NOT PRINT THIS LINE, SO IT IS TELLING ME IT DID NOT FIND THE RECORD

            ...(There's more to this function but it's unnecessary)
```

I also confirmed that when the query begins, the predicate/"thisTeamName" is supposed to be what it is, which is the groupName of the record just created. I am confused on why it is not able to retrieve/query for the record.

Comment: Same issue. Duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729601/how-to-update-data-in-tableview-without-the-delay-using-cloudkit-when-creating-n/42731220#42731220

Comment: Why do you first store records and then in the same application immediately retrieve records? Isn‘t Cloudkit for transferring, and CoreData/Realm/simple structs/etc. for local caching/storing? I mean what‘s the goal in doing this here? Not having to maintain local storage? Simplifying code with „online-first“?

Answer (score 1):

Your refresh function calls loadGroupPage() then immediately fires off an async call to reload the tables without waiting for the loadGroupPage function to complete so even if you do get a record I don't think it's going to work properly.

You don't show in the loadGroupPage function where you actually add your request operation to a database.  I'm assuming that's in there?

The recordFetchedBlock will fire once for each record returned, you don't need to force unwrap the record (record: CKRecord!). You also don't need to check record != nil since it's guaranteed to be there.

The CKQuery recordFetchedBlock docs say:

> **Warning**
>
> Query indexes are updated asynchronously so they are not guaranteed to be current. If you query for records that you recently changed and not allow enough time for those changes to be processed, the query results may be incorrect. The results may not contain the correct records and the records may be out of order.

I'm not an expert by any means (and haven't used the convenience API) but have built syncing into my app and just from my experience I'd be surprised if the problem is the index hasn't updated.

**I would recommend adding in a queryCompletionBlock and check for errors there.** You should always be checking for errors when using CloudKit because even when the code is right there will still be times when you get errors (network unavailable, iCloud down, etc.)

Comment: 1) reloading the table should not matter because the print line inside the query is not being called. 2) yes, at the end. 3) unnecessary 4) may be the issue 5) I already have a completion block where I check for errors. soooooooo.....

Comment: So you're getting no errors, no record back but the record exists when you check for it.  You've tried just querying for all records that exist I'm guessing? That returns nothing either?  And what about doing a query NOT immediately after creating the record.  I'm still dubious it's an indexing issue - things have seemed to return immediately when I've done them (although I haven't used the convenience API)

Comment: I'm just working around it. Still have the issue but don't care very much about it rn. Thx for ur help

Comment: This might apply to your situation.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824301/in-cloudkit-after-adding-a-record-the-new-record-will-not-appear-in-a-query-th